# Python subprocess on win32 not working without with shell=True

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

It may seem weird but I am trying to use Perl's CPAN in a Python script through subprocess.check_call(). For some reason it does not work and gives the following error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

When I try to run the command normally.

Using shell=True fixes the problem, but I have read that this can have some security concerns. Can someone explain to me why this is happening and is there a way to fix it?

EDIT: Sample code

Here is how I run through the list with check_call():

```
packages = {'DateTime':'2','Win32::API':'2','Date::Manip':'2','XML::LibXML':'2','Carp::Assert':'2',
                    'Digest::CRC':'2','Data::Hexify':'2','Image::ExifTool':'2','File::Mork':'2','DateTime::Format::Strptime':'2',
                    'Parse::Win32Registry':'2','HTML::Scrubber':'2','Mac::PropertyList':'2','XML::Entities':'2'}

for k,v in packages.iteritems():
    try:
        res = check_call(shlex.split('cpan install %s' % k), shell=True)
        if res == 0:
            v = 0
    except CalledProcessError:
```

Thanks!

Comment: What command are you trying to run? Where does it live? Are you using a full path to it or just the bare name?

Comment: I am trying to run a number of commands to install perl packages, one for example is 'cpan install Win32::API'... All follow this same convention where Win32::API is the package name... It is just the bare name but the cpan dir is in my System and User %PATH%

Comment: Could you give an example of how you write one of your check_call()'s?

Comment: Edited with an example, thanks for the help!

Comment: Does using a full path to `cpan` make it work without using the shell?

Comment: @EtanReisner, Nope, still the same behavior with the full path provided

Comment: For what it's worth, semantics are very, *very* different between UNIX and Windows. Whereas use of `shell=True` is typically dangerous on UNIX, that may not be the case on win32. (I don't know the win32 semantics, and can't speak either way with regard to them).

Comment: (as an aside, the `shlex.split()` here is creating potential for bugs; you'd be safer passing `['cpan', 'install', k]`, unless your intent is for any whitespace inside of `k` to create additional arguments).

Comment: Edited the title to attract folks who actually know the Windows semantics, since us UNIX folks may not be able to help as much. :)

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `check_call()` over `Popen()`? `Popen()` should work.

Comment: Hmm, not really other than that I wanted to check the return code, I presume it's just as easy with `Popen()`. I could use that then

Comment: I'll post some example code in the answer section because code does not format nicely in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

subprocess.Popen(), with stdout redirected so you can check the output.

```
import subprocess as s
import shlex

k = "DateTime"

proc = s.Popen(["cpan", "install", k], stdout=s.PIPE)
output, err = proc.communicate()

print output, err
```

Comment: I have the same error with this as with `check_call()`

Comment: Please type the output of this:
`import os`
`print os.environ["COMSPEC"]`

Comment: `C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe`

Comment: This is really strange. According to [the popen constructor part of the python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) it says on Windows the only time you should have to use shell=True is when you're calling built-ins. I'm pretty certain that cpan isn't a windows built-in.

Comment: Yeah, cpan most definitely is not, I installed it today under Strawberry perl, the full path is `c:\strawberry\perl\bin\cpan`

Comment: By any chance do you have cygwin installed?

Comment: Yes, I do - would that matter?

Comment: When I use the windows `where` command, to see where the binaries are located, it says my cygwin cpan comes first. That might mean it uses the cygwin version first, when you want to use the strawberry perl version. You have two perls installed. Perhaps `shell=True` might be needed here.